# Can I hire a car and drive from Berlin to Gdansk?

Tags: car-rentals

My wife and I would like to drive from Berlin to Gdansk but can't find any car rental companies that will allow this.

Comment: Would that be a one-way trip or would you go to Gdansk and return the car in Berlin afterwards? Edit: For example: Sixt has no problem at all if you rent a car there and use it to go to Poland. Only certain restrictions apply regarding some models.

Comment: It would be a one way trip..WE would like to leave the car in Gdansk

Comment: So, can confirm it is no problem with Sixt. One way rental and returning the car in Poland. Also, not sure which companies you checked, because my quick research has shown that most large rental companies have no problem at all with one way rentals to Poland.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not directly answer to your question but probably the best what you can do is to rent a car in Berlin for using it there (if you need one). Return car and go by bus to Szczecin (plenty of connections starting 8euros) which is less than 2h driving and there rent a car that you'll return in Gdańsk

Comment: Suggest some rental companies that will allow this as well. Thanks.